# Has Scarlett Johansson ever sung well (in universe)?

Tags: soundtrack, acting

In the "Lost in Translation" we can see Charlotte (Scarlet) goofing with Bob (Murray) in the karaoke bar - we can see that she is rather trying to have fun than perform well.

In "The Other Boleyn Girl", when forced to sing in front of the queen (who knows, that she is supposed to be a new king's lover), she sings weakly, with causes other ladies to snicker and the queen to sarcastically comment "bravo... a nightingale" (at around 2:15)

But then Scarlet arguably CAN sing and even published an album - you can hear it for example here:

So, has she ever sung well in a movie? By "well" - I mean in a way, that wasn't **purposefully bad** and was well accepted by other characters?

To precise: in "LiT" Charlotte is not trying to be a good singer, in "tOBG" Mary is trying to sing well but is played in a way which makes the effect obviously bad. I am asking has Scarlet's character tried to sing well and the effect wasn't badly received in obvious fashion (snickering, embarrassed looks etc) by other movie characters - was it good or bad for the viewer is not relevant.

Comment: How can we define **sings well* or *bad-singer*? maybe actor/actress may have to sing bad, it depends on the movie. if you're asking whether an actor/actress can really sing in the real life, them I'm afraid this is falling under off-topic

Comment: @Vishwa I am not asking was it good or bad for the viewer, but rather was it MEANT to be good (and possibly was - without an obvious snickering, embarrassment etc) for the other characters in the movie

Comment: While I don't think the question is bad per se, I think it falls off-topic as trivia.

Answer (score 2):

She sings quite beautifully in the film "Her"

Answer (score 2):

"Trust in me" from *The Jungle Book* (2016) is not portrayed as a bad performance.

I've not seen *Sing* (2016) but I assume at least one of the performances there is not intended to be bad.

Comment: Ash gets a standing ovation during _Sing_’s climax for her performance of “Set It All Free” (which is also supposed to be the character’s original composition). (All of the characters get standing ovations for their performances—it wasn’t exactly supposed to be a tough crowd—but nonetheless. If we want a tougher crowd, during Ash’s performance the film cuts to her ex’s new girlfriend seeing it on TV and acting unimpressed, followed by the ex secretly watching the rest of the performance in awe after the new girl leaves the room.)